# How to get rid of the below message in cassandra logs?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I have recently upgraded datastax-enterprise from 4.8.16 to 5.0.15. We are using password authentication in PlainText format. But below message is continuously coming in logs.

```
2018-12-11 09:50:04.446 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-5 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 09:50:37.465 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-1 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 09:50:49.472 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-4 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 09:55:43.148 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-2 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 09:57:50.736 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-3 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 09:59:33.013 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-3 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 10:00:04.450 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-3 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 10:00:37.469 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-3 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 10:00:49.475 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-4 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 10:05:43.364 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-2 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 10:07:50.840 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-3 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
2018-12-11 10:09:33.658 WARN   [SharedPool-Worker-2 - com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator:411] Plain text authentication without client / server encryption is strongly discouraged
```

How to get rid of this message as I am not interest to use encryption for now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set:

```
authentication_options:
    plain_text_without_ssl: allow
```

in your `dse.yaml` configuration file. The possible settings for this are:

```
block  - block the request with an authentication error
warn   - log a warning about the request but allow it to continue (default)
allow  - allow the request without any warning
```

Comment: Awesome ... Thanks.